# Git Log of only one branch that has already been merged (without knowing branch name)

Tags: git, git-log

I need to generate logs for git in a branch-by-branch way, but I don't necessarily know the name of the branch that I need to get the logs for. However, I do have the commit IDs for the first and last commit of the branch that I need the logs for. However, this branch has already been merged into the branch that I'm getting the logs from and I only want the commit messages from that branch, and not any branches that have had merges between the beginning and end of my branch. Visually:

```
       C----D
      /      \
A-------------M---F------M---H
   \               \    /
    B-----------E---M--G
```

NOTE: M represents a merge from one branch into another

If I'm at H and have the commit IDs for B and G, how do I write a git log message to only get the messages for B,E, and G?

Currently I have

```
git log $beginCommit --no-merges --max-count=1 > changes.txt
git log $beginCommit..$endCommit --no-merges >> changes.txt
```

But in this case that would return B,C,D,E,F,G. Is there a way where I can specify to get the logs only for the branch that originally had the two commits?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: If your graph drawing is accurate, this *won't* include commits C, D, and F. G is shown as having one parent, namely E; E has one parent B. So the graph walk goes G, E, B and since B is the `$beginCommit`, stops there.

Comment: @torek you're right, I actually missed an aspect here where the middle branch is merged into the bottom branch before G, updating my drawing

Comment: If all the merges were done in the "right direction" (merges are partly symmetric so it's possible they weren't), use `--first-parent` to follow only the first parent through the merge commits.

Comment: @torek ah, that's what I've tried. Maybe I need to have a talk with my team in establishing patterns in the "right direction".

Comment: With "wrong direction" merges (these happen when people use `git pull` for instance), you will have to find each merge that brings in an unwanted chain, and do something to stop the revision-walking at that point and resume it at the wanted parent. This can be pretty tricky.